# Two check-box's in one check-box list

Tags: c#, ms-access, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am currently working on converting an application from access to C# and have come across an odd control I need to replicate. In access there is a list of check-box's, for the current month the user is looking at, which has everyday of that month with two check-box's beside it, D and N (for day and night). So my question is what would be the best way to implement this. I am thinking of creating it programatically with two check-box lists side by side but wondering if you can put two box's in one list

```
June 1 [D] [N]
...
June 31 [D] [N]
```

Comment: I see no reason for the ms-access tag here, as it is completely tangential to the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) and create two CheckBoxColumns in it

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to maintain the exact look and feel, you can use two checkboxes side by side with a separate Label control, then pop them in a [DataRepeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsdata/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms) to repeat them for each row of data.

However, using a [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) with two checkbox columns will be *much* easier.